# Angular universal app in PHP app subfolder

Tags: angular, angular-universal

I'm facing a problem I haven't been able to find information about. The thing is, I have an angular universal app and need to put it on a url like http://example.com/universal, but, the site under http://example.com is a php site, so, the question is... Is there a way I can host my angular universal app in that url knowing that the base site is in a PHP server? can I "mount" a nodejs server under http://example.com/universal to run the angular universal app?

Comment: You would have to be able to run anything on the server. Besides that, you can have as many separate machines under subdomain/paths as you want

Comment: But, is it enough? I mean, if I place my angular universal app in the subfolder, how can I tell the server to execute the main.js server file when it gets to that specific path?

Comment: you cant. Thats the point. You have to have nodejs running on server

Comment: Yes you can. You have to use a proxy and it depends upon which server you are running. Both Apache and nginx support proxy configurations. You'll run the NodeJS server on a different port, and then *route* proxy requests for that path to that port.

Comment: Did you solve this? I'm facing the same problem.